# Form submission error using Formspree

Tags: html, forms, email

I used Formspree to send the information from form to my email. Once I hit the submission button, I get 404 resource not found (process.php) error in console, even though my 'action=' attribute redirects to a link

```
<form action="https://formspree.io/myemail@gmail.com" id="contact-form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST">

              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-subject" name="form-subject" placeholder="Subiect" required>

              <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" id="form-message" name="form-message" placeholder="message" required></textarea>
                  <div class="text-center">
                      <button type="submit" class="battn">Submit</button>
                  </div>
</form>
```

I even tried adding a Referrer as meta tag in the body

```
<meta name="Referrer" content="origin">
```

Answer (score 1):

Just found what went wrong! The form id was being called by process.php. Changed it's id, now works fine

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [this](https://help.formspree.io/articles/5951-unable-to-submit-form-error) Formspree article:

> - You are **testing your site** by opening it in a browser as a **static HTML file in your computer's filesystem**. In this case its URL will not start with http:// or https://. **This will not work**, because browsers don't treat these pages as normal web resources and thus they do not automatically send the "Referer" header when you submit a form. Formspree requires that header to work. This can be solved if you just open your HTML files as a web resource from a local web server. If you're on Mac or Linux, just type python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000 or your HTML files directory and visit http://localhost:8000 on your browser. If you're on Windows, try installing one of the following super simple web servers: [Web server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb), [thttpd](https://acme.com/software/thttpd/) or Quickshare.

Comment: This was the problem for me. Great answer!

Comment: @Rexcirus No problem. Though seeing my answer has just revealed to me just how horrid my grammar is. Definitely editing my comment off